# Preg_match for items in a list

Tags: regex, preg-match

EDIT: The answer and comment below make me think that I didn't explain this clearly... I am looking for a regular expression that matches multiple occurrences of a list. For example, I might want to take ABCBCBCBCBCD and I want to get the array [BC, BC, BC, BC, BC] from it. I don't know how many items will be in the list. If it is ABCD, I want the list [bc]. If it is ABCBCD, I want [bc, bc]. I thouht I could use /A(BC)+D/ to match all occurrences of BC, but that is not working.

The original question...

I have a set of very large data files. Per file, I only want a list of items out of it. The information I'm looking for has the format:

```
...<RXCUI> <LN ID=531123>Amoxicillin</LN>, <LN ID=441656>Amikacin</LN></ERS>...
```

The ... means that there is tons of text before and after this set. I can easily get the first item listed using the regex

```
preg_match('~<RXCUI>[^<]*(<LN[^>]*>[^<]*</LN>[^<]*)~', $data, $matches);
```

Then, $matches[1] has "Amoxicillin, ". I tried to get all matches in the list using:

```
preg_match('~<RXCUI>[^<]*(<LN[^>]*>[^<]*</LN>[^<]*)+~', $data, $matches);
```

That doesn't work. I get no matches. What is the syntax for "Multiple matches for the preceding sequence between ( and )"?

Of note, this is what is in $matches:

```
Array (
  [0] => <RXCUI> <LN ID=531123>Amoxicillin</LN>, <LN ID=441656>Amikacin</LN>
  [1] => <LN ID=531123>Amoxicillin</LN>
)
```

So, it looked at both items in the list, but only returned the first one. What I want is:

```
Array (
  [0] => <RXCUI> <LN ID=531123>Amoxicillin</LN>, <LN ID=441656>Amikacin</LN>
  [1] => <LN ID=531123>Amoxicillin</LN>
  [2] => <LN ID=441655>Akikacin</LN>
)
```

Comment: isn't this https://regex101.com/r/dZ0vZ3/1 ok?

Comment: @rock321987 That will not work. That matches all LN entries. I only want the LN entries that follow the RXCUI tag.

Comment: All the contents of `LN` tag within `RXCUI` or only the first?

Comment: I want every LN element in an array so I can run a foreach loop over all the elements. I can easily get all LN elements as a big blob of a string. I'm trying to get them as an array of items, not a big string.

Comment: So the number of <LN> tags that follow an <RXCUI> tag are variable (could be 1 or 2 or 4 etc.)? Is there a grander string to deal with?  Can you provide a new sample with a bit more length that shows this? Please also include the expected result with your new sample. This will clarify your question and enable SO users to understand your question and potentially provide the best approach.  Are there multiple <RXCUI> tags in the string? Other things to consider? Doing two waves of `preg_match()` seems too expensive.

Comment: @mickmackusa The stream I was reading from was literally a stream. I was copying it in blocks to a temp file. Parsing it, and then flushing it. I ended up writing flags. I wrote one that would increment when it hit <RXCUI> and would decrement when it hit </RXCUI> (sometimes, those are embedded, causing confusion about what was required). Then, I wrote one for <LN> and </LN>. When RXCUI and LN were positive, I copied all contents into another tmp file. When </LN> caused the count to go to zero, I embedded a newline in the tmp file so I could easily read it line by line and get the LNs.

Comment: @kainaw  This question doesn't yet have an accepted answer, so I'll assume you are still looking for a quality solution.  Please post a larger sample input in your question for testing that includes some of the troublesome features that you are contending with.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
preg_match_all("/(\<RXCUI\>.*\<\/LN\>)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fpc

Comment: That will spit out the entire list as one array item. Correct? What I'm trying to do is get each item in the list as an independent array item.

Comment: True.. But can't you just explode the result on "," and you will have your two parts (or more)? With pattern: `\<RXCUI\> (\<LN .*\>.*<\/LN\>)` you only get the LN parts in an array if you use preg_match_all

Comment: That assumes there are no commas in the values. So, I have to work out a way to identify only the commas that I want to explode on. That is what I have to do since I can't get a regex that returns a variable number of matches.

Comment: @kainaw If you use preg_split you can keep the delimiter. So with a delimiter of "</LN>, <LN" it will most likely only split where you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, it appears that this cannot be done with a single preg_match function. It requires two passes. The first will pull the entire match from the beginning to the end of the list. The second will break the list into the matches that are desired.

The first pass (assume $s = ...<RXCUI> <LN ID=531123>Amoxicillin</LN>, <LN ID=441656>Amikacin</LN></ERS>...)

```
preg_match('~<RXCUI>[^<]*(<LN[^>]*>[^<]*</LN>[^<]*)+</ERS>~', $s, $match1);
```

Now, $match1[0] = <RXCUI> <LN ID=531123>Amoxicillin</LN>, <LN ID=441656>Amikacin</LN></ERS>
I can use preg_match_all to get just what I want between the RXCUI and ERS elements

```
preg_match_all('~<LN[^>]*>[^<]*</LN>~', $match1[0], $match2);
```

Now, $match2[0] will contain an array:

```
[0] => <LN ID=531123>Amoxicillin</LN>
[1] => <LN ID=441656>Amikacin</LN>
```

It doesn't matter how many LN lines there are, the second preg_match_all will return them all.

This could be simplified a great deal if you could ensure that there are no LN elements anywhere else in the original document. I know that they are are LN elements that are not part of the RXCUI section. So, I can't just look for those.